# How to change the value of a table data depends on a conditio inside the ng-repeat | AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I have a table of orders, and depend on the order type i want to change the value of the `td`. below is my view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="invoice in allInvoices">
    <td>{{invoice.order_type}}</td>
    <td>{{invoice.order_date}}</td>
    <td>{{invoice.totalPrice}}</td>
    <td>{{invoice.client_name}}</td>
</tr>
```

i tried:

```
<td ng-if="invoice.order_type='M'">Mobile</td>
<td ng-if="invoice.order_type='A'">Accessories</td>
```

but this don't fit with my table view since it will show two `td`, while i want to keep on one `td` but change it's value depends on the order type.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might have a typo in your `ng-if` conditions? It looks like you're using assignment rather than equality (i.e. `invoice.order_type === 'M'`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use an expression like

```
{{invoice.order_type == 'M' ? 'Mobile' : invoice.order_type == 'A' ? 'Accesories' : 'other'}}
```

the scheme is the following:

```
{{expression ? ifTrue : otherExpression ? ifTrue : anotherExpression ? ifTrue : ifFalse}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
<td>{{invoice.order_type=='M'?'Mobile':'Accessories'}}</td>
```

OR a lookup with a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors):

```
<td>{{orderTypeName[invoice.order_type]}}</td>
```

```
$scope.orderTypeName = {
    'M': 'Mobile',
    'A': 'Accessories',
};
```

This avoids using `ng-if` with the consequent child scope.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<td ng-if="invoice.order_type==='M'">Mobile</td>
<td ng-if="invoice.order_type==='A'">Accessories</td>
```

`=` is value assignment, where as inside `ng-if` there is always conditional statement ,i.e, use `===`

Answer (score -1):

Try comparison operator `==` instead of assignment operator `=`

```
<td ng-if="invoice.order_type=='M'">Mobile</td>
<td ng-if="invoice.order_type=='A'">Accessories</td>
```